# How to call function in another class?

Tags: php

I have `getVaraible()` which return `$variable`. And now I want to call`getVariable()` from `class A` in getVaraibleFromAntoherClass()`in`class B`. How can I do that ?

```
class A
{
    private ?string $variable = null;

    public function getVariable(): string
    {
        if ($this->variable === null) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return $this->variable;

    }
}
```

```
class B
{

    function getVaraibleFromAntoherClass(): string
    {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: `(new B())->getVaraibleFromAntoherClass()`? If you don't have an instance of B, I'm not sure why the function is needed in the first place. Did you mean to declare it static? It's impossible to tell with redacted names, sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a method of an object inside another class in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703309/how-to-call-a-method-of-an-object-inside-another-class-in-php)